# Clion external tools output not showing anymore?

Tags: console, clion, ros

I configured two external tools commands

1. catkin build my_project
2. roslaunch my_project my_launch.launch

Now when I invoke command 1 I see the output and everything works. When I launch the second command also everything gets started and works, but I don't see any output. At the beginning I had only command 2 and it did show me my output, then after adding command 1, I didn't get any output anymore. Now I tried to remove command 1 to only have command 2 but I still see no output. What gives?
This is how the command is configured
[image]